# Flutter iOS build fails randomly

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I keep facing intermittent build failures for the ios build of my Flutter project.  Android is working fine.  Every few days this happens, and then I do a combination of deleting my `Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` file, `pod cache clean --all`, and running `pod install`, and the errors magically go away.  This time however, nothing seems to be working and I keep getting the errors.

I am completely stuck and would really appreciate any help from my fellow developers.  Here is the log I get when trying to run on iOS simulator (the weird part is that the errors are always different on every build):

UPDATE MAY 14th:

So after doing a number of things, I am now getting another error. I did a `flutter run --verbose` and in the logs I noticed this:

```
The path does not exist
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

After some more digging I realized it's coming from `xcode_backend.sh` (in the `Flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/directory`). It's because the property FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH isn't defined.

I see this property in ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig, so I don't know where else it should be defined. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't worry about the no `lib/main.dart` file error.  I have a file called `lib/main_dev.dart` which I specify, and like I said it usually works.

Comment: Errors like this are difficult to reproduce. Does your drive has a cloud syncing services such as Google Drive or One Drive or like ? Since it works with main_dev.dart, I don't think the problem is not having file 'main.dart' and since it only intermittently happens, there has to be some compile time problem (or cache).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error could be related to flutterToast. Have you tried removing it from you pubsec.yaml and your code and see if it alleviates the issues you see. Another go to I usually do when facing similar iOS/pod issues is I run pod install from the terminal in the iOS folder then try to build from Xcode. Most times the error messages are more descriptive that way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Look like is flutter 1.17 problems.
Hope that can fix the problem in next dependencies update.

Same situation with ur problems.
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2530

Answer (score -1):

From the log I see it looks like one of the libraries you use, uses deprecated or/and unused language or native library API. I would try to remove `^` symbol from your `yaml` file and downgrade to the latest stable version or update to the newest your libraries - it may help you to get rig of warnings. The main error is the one regarding missing `main` method. Build fails because of that. Builds don't fail due to the warnings but only dou to the errors. And the only error Ctrl-F finds in your log - the Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': No such file or directory
package:myProject/main.dart: Error: No 'main' method found.

I know you said that you supply other file but flutter plugin may not be as stable as you think so it may just confuse it. Try to add main.dart with `main` method there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I tried with just the `main.dart` file and now Iget this error:  === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH
> CONFIGURATION Release ===
>     The path  does not exist
>     Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255